# Why do chat notifications only appear when chat is open?

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, notifications

I keep desktop notifications enabled for chat. However, I notice that notifications only appear if the chat — any chat, not necessarily the one from which I'm actually getting the notification — is open, even if only in the background.

Is this a bug, or is this just a limitation in the notification system? If the latter, is there a way to fix it? Is it by design?

Comment: I think it is by design. I think that the system sends notifications when received a message from a websocket with the javascript code `new Notification()`.  And the javascript for the notifications does not work when the tab is closed